# Digital root with squared digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n = n_0 + \dots + n_{t-1}10^{t-1}$ is nonnegative integer let's denote
$$ S(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} n_k $$
$$ T(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{t-1} n_k^2 $$
It is well known that sequence $S(n), S(S(n)), \dots $ stabilizes to one-digit integer called [digital root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) of $n$.

The sequence $T(n), T(T(n)), \dots$ needn't stabilize. It can be cyclic as, for example, with $n = 4$:
$$ 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, \dots$$

Let's call the smallest number in sequence $T(n), T(T(n)), \dots$ "the squared digital root of $n$". While the ordinary digital root has pretty properties like
$$dr(n) = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
0, & n = 0\\ 
9,  & n \neq 0, n \equiv 0 \left(\text{mod} ~9\right)\\ 
n ~ \text{mod} ~ 9, & n \not\equiv 0 \left(\text{mod} ~9\right)
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
I wonder whether there's an efficient way to compute the squared digital root.

One obvious approach is to keep track of which numbers have occured so far and return the smallest of them when the repetition occurs. But such an algorithm will be too slow for big inputs. So is there a more mathematical approach like the one above?

EDIT

In a question [Repeated sum of square of digits always arrives at $1$ or $89$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933385/repeated-sum-of-square-of-digits-always-arrives-at-1-or-89) mentioned by @dhiv it's shown that sequence $T(n), T(T(n)), \dots$ will eventually end up in one of two cycles: $(1)$ or $(89,145,42,20,4,16,37,58)$.

This means that squared digital root of $n$ is not greater than $4$: $sdr(n) \leq 4$. But there's still a question: how to find which of this four numbers is the answer.

Comment: See [project Euler problem 92](https://projecteuler.net/problem=92) and [Repeated sum of square of digits always arrives at 1 or 89](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933385/repeated-sum-of-square-of-digits-always-arrives-at-1-or-89).

Comment: @dxivThanks for your comment. I'll take a look now.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks again. It's really interesting that the sequence will end up in one of two loops: (1) or (89,145,42,20,4,16,37,58). This fact reduces the original problem to the question whether we can get 1, 2, 3 or 4 on some stage. I still don't get how to check this.

Comment: It's enough to check the numbers $1, 2, \ldots 99$ to determine that, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933385/repeated-sum-of-square-of-digits-always-arrives-at-1-or-89#comment3969125_1933398).

Comment: @Peter T(111) = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3

Comment: @Igor Of course ...

Comment: @dhiv Nice idea but how can i check which of these numbers (1,...,99) will appear in sequence T(n), ... for particular n? I believe that there must be some modular recurrence relation like in the case of ordinary digital root.

Comment: Are the possible cycles also known for cubes instead of squares ? For example, $153$ and $407$ are fixpoints and $(55/250/133)$ is a cycle.

Comment: @Peter At least 133 - 55 - 250 - 133 ))

Comment: @Peter I believe that this problem deserves a separate question. It's interesting.

Comment: Should I post it ?

Comment: Why not? It seems to be a challenging question.