# Which cycles are possible by repeated summation of the cubes of the digits of a number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, perfect-powers

Here :

[Digital root with squared digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682930/digital-root-with-squared-digits)

the possible cycles of repeated summation of the squares of the digits of a number are mentioned. What about cubes ?

$1$ , $153$ , $370$ , $371$ and $407$ are fixpoints

$(136/244)$ , $(919/1459)$ , $(160/217/352)$ and $(55/250/133)$ are cycles.

> What is the complete set of the possible cycles ?

Comment: Since the sum of the cubes of the digits of $n$ is smaller than $n$ for $n \geqslant N_0$, where $N_0 < 3000$, a computer search should be quick.

Comment: @DanielFischer  So, if every number $n\le 10^4$ arrives at one of the numbers above , does this prove that there are no more cycles ?

Comment: @DanielFischer And upto which number do we have to check in the case of $k$-th powers ?

Comment: Yes, and you can stop some time before $10^4$.

Comment: For the $k^{\text{th}}$ powers, the sum for a $d$-digit number is at most $d\cdot 9^k$. So as soon as $10^{d-1} > d\cdot 9^k$ you know all cycles involve only numbers with fewer than $d$ digits. One can then push the limit a bit lower by looking at how large the sum can actually become.

Comment: And, just to emphasise: This shows that (for every $k$) every number leads to a cycle (including cycles of length $1$, i.e. fixed points).

Comment: So e.g. for $k = 4$ one notes that $d\cdot 9^4 < 10^{d-1}$ for $d \geqslant 6$, thus one deals at most with $5$-digit numbers. That makes the maximal achievable sum $5 \cdot 6561 < 33000$, hence you have at most four nines and one three to deal with, which gives a bound of twenty-something thousand.