# Will iterating the sum of the squares of the digits of any number ultimately give $1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

I was doing a program where I had to figure out whether the sum of square of digits of a number will ultimately give $1$. For eg:
$$68 \;\to\; 6^2+8^2=36+64=100 \;\to\; 1^2+0^2+0^2=1$$

So I wanted to know if this loop gives a single digit number ultimately for every number.

Comment: A necessary (but probably not sufficient) condition is that the number of elements (i.e. digits) in the original number that are not congruent to $0 \pmod{3}$ must be a number that is congruent to $1 \pmod{3}$.  This is because any number that is congruent to $0 \pmod{3}$ will have the sum of the digits of its square also congruent to $0 \pmod{3}$.  Similarly, if the number is not congruent to $0 \pmod{3}$, then the sum of the digits of its square will automatically be congruent to $1 \pmod{3}.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeated sum of square of digits always arrives at $1$ or $89$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933385/repeated-sum-of-square-of-digits-always-arrives-at-1-or-89)

Comment: ^ Every number leads to $1$ or $4$

Comment: @MangoPizza How?

Comment: @NiveditaChowdhury Go to the post and you'll find Robert Z's proof that every number does lead to a single digit number which is either $1$ or $4$.

Answer (score -1):

Let S(x) be the sum of the squares of the digits of x. You first find T = largest number x so that S(x) >= x. Obviously starting with an x > T will end up with an integer <= T. You can show that T = 99. So you examine all numbers up to 99 and check which cycle they end in.